# Add shutdown hook does not log all data

Tags: java, concurrency, vert.x

We have a vert.x java application wherein we need to log some information when it is shutdown. However, when pressing CTRL+C or when java application is shut down, only "Shutting down..." is the only one printed.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(serviceStatusLogger::log));

   final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        final HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

        final Router router = Router.router(Vertx.vertx());
        final Route route = router.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/health");

        route.handler(request -> {
            final HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
            response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
            response.end(makeResponse());
        });

        server.requestHandler(router).listen(8085);
```

The ServiceStatusLogger class contains all data that needs to be logged. How do I ensure that all the loggers here printed when program is shut down?

```
public class ServiceStatusLogger {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServiceStatusLogger.class.getName());

    private final DefaultMessageResolver defaultMessageResolver;
    private final WebhookResponseRepository webhookResponseRepository;

    public ServiceStatusLogger(final DefaultMessageResolver defaultMessageResolver,
                               final WebhookResponseRepository webhookResponseRepository) {
        this.defaultMessageResolver = defaultMessageResolver;
        this.webhookResponseRepository = webhookResponseRepository;
    }


    public void log(){

        LOG.info("Shutting down...");
        LOG.info("Last processed webhook response log id: " + webhookResponseRepository
                .getLastWebhookResponseLog()
                .getId());
        LOG.info("Total number of webhooks processed in this job execution: "
                + defaultMessageResolver.getWebhooksProcessed());
    }
}
```

Comment: Shutdown hooks must execute quickly and not engage in blocking actions such as network I/IO. See the documentation. You can't do this.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this in vert.x aside from using shutdown hooks

Comment: Log as you go. Why do you have pending log messages at shutdown? Design error there.